# SimpleDateFormat: Unparseable date when I try parse month: MMM dd, yyyy

Tags: java, date

I try to parse string do the Date format, but get Unparserable exception:

```java
    public void roundTest() throws ParseException {
        String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String from = "Jul 01, 2021";
        Date result = sdf.parse(from);
    }
```

The same for `java.time` package:

```java
    public void roundTest() throws ParseException {
        String from = "Jul 01, 2021";
        String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(from, formatter));
    }
```

Error: `"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jul 01, 2021' could not be parsed at index 0"`

Where the error?

Comment: Works fine. https://ideone.com/08boTR

Comment: You should **not** use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, as they are obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: What is your default locale? Maybe the 3-character month name is different there?

Comment: Here is [an example](https://ideone.com/0kqPKm) using `java.time`.

Comment: @MCEmperor the same for 'java.time'. Please see updated question

Comment: java.time is helpful enough to tell us where the problem is: index 0, that is, `Jul`. Which confirms that the locale is the problem as mentioned in the linked questions, since July isn’t abbreviated in this way in all locales.

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/PNfEiW) is @MCEmperor’s example modified to specify a locale explicitly so that the code also works in non-English locales.